# How to create a Tabview on WatchOS using Objective C or Xamarin storyboards?

Tags: xamarin.ios, watchos, xcode-storyboard

I know that Objective C is not supported for WatchOs any longer and SwiftUi is the only option but using Xamarin Ios, it is still available at least for now and i want to create a quick app still using Storyboards on Xcode. So question is nothing related to Xamarin although I use Xamarin to create WatchOS project but Storyboards are done on Xcode. I cannot find any control called Tabcontoller or tabview on storyboard. How is it created or how was it created before swiftUi? When i google tabview WatchOs, I see only examples for SwiftUi.